# Box inside a box / CSS + DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn css and html to do something, but isn't working.

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

But this is what i'm getting:

[image]

My code:

```css
#agenda1 { width: 350px; height: 50px; background-color: white; } #agenda2{ height: 23px; background-color: #bf1a17; border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 60; } #textoagenda{ text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="agenda1"> <div id="agenda2" float="left"> <div id="textoagenda"> 26/25 </div </div> </div>
```

Comment: <div id="agenda1">
<div id="agenda2" float="left">
<div id="textoagenda">
26/25
</div
</div>
</div>

#agenda1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
#agenda2{
height: 23px;
background-color: #bf1a17;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 60;
}
#textoagenda{
text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the  numbers in an element and make it `inline-block` so that it will display inline with the text but you can apply vertical padding, `border-radius` for rounded corners, `padding` as you see fit, a `background-color`, and `vertical-align` so it will align properly with the text beside it.

```css
span {
  background: #c00011;
  border-radius: .75em;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>26/25</span> TESTTESTASDFASDF
```

Answer (score 0):

add margin property your main div.

```css
#agenda1 { width: 350px; 
height: 50px; 
background-color: white;
margin:auto; }

 #agenda2{ height: 23px; 
background-color: #bf1a17; 
border-radius: 10px; 
margin-top: 10px; 
width: 60; } 

#textoagenda{
 text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="agenda1"> <div id="agenda2" float="left"> <div id="textoagenda"> 26/25 </div </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, try this

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#box1{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

#box2{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box1">contents</div>
<div id="box2">contenst</div>
</body>
</html>
```